# Can't start project window on client side with visual studio live share

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-liveshare

My friend has opened a live share in vs studio
when I try to start up the project, instead of opening the window on my screen
it opens up on his.
it is a simple window with a textbox.

how can I change that it will open on my computer instead?

and I cannot open the design view too.

Answer (score 0):

1: He needs to open the project he wants to share.
2: Start the live share.
3: It(VS) puts a link in the clip board and he needs to email you the link.
4: You open the email and click the link.
5: Visual Studio should launch with the project he shared.
That's pretty much it...

Comment: i am in the project  i entered it already pressed the link

Comment: If he sent you the link...Then just close Visual Studio...then just click the link. It should open VS with the project he is sharing.

Comment: I am in his project but when I try to start the project it opens the form on his computer and not mine while saying it is running

Comment: I see the debug not the actual build